# how to cancel out a function when another function is running

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a samll code where i have a circle going left or right or standing still when i press left, right arrow or nothing using keyPress and keyReleased functions.It is working fine but I want to fix a small problem when I for example I press **Right** then **Left** and then releases **Right**.

This will cause the cricle to stand still and I assume it is because the release function was the last one executed even though keyPressed is still active(? just guessing).
Iam am wondering if there is a way to fix this small problem?

Current code:

```
function keyReleased() {

  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW || keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    players.stop() // Will cause drag on the circle to stop it

  }
}

function keyPressed() {

  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    players.dir(2)  // Will cause the circle to move right 

  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    players.dir(-2) // Will cause the circle to move left

  }
}
```

Comment: disable/do not react when one is active..

Comment: Can you add a code snippet with your code so we can run and help debug your program for you? (See here for more detail: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992))

Answer (score 0):

You can create currentState like history, and push on all press. Stop when pressed keys are released. meaning empty state

```js
let currentState = [];
const remove = (arr, val) => arr.filter((x) => x != val);
function keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    currentState = remove(currentState, LEFT_ARROW);
  }
  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    currentState = remove(currentState, RIGHT_ARROW);
  }
  if (!currentState.length) players.stop(); // Will cause drag on the circle to stop it
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    players.dir(2); // Will cause the circle to move right
    currentState.push(RIGHT_ARROW);
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    players.dir(-2); // Will cause the circle to move left
    currentState.push(LEFT_ARROW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a while loop could solve your problem that way you could put all of the functionality in one function. That way they won't cancel each other out. Also, using a switch statement might be beneficial especially if you end up integrating up and down arrows.

```
function movePlayer() {
    while(keyPressed) {
        switch(keyCode):
            case LEFT_ARROW:
                players.dir(-2);
            case RIGHT_ARROW:
                players.dir(2);
            default:
                players.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the player direction you can increment and decrement them when a key is pressed.

Add a `change_dir` method to the player class and do nt set the direction, but change it:
(I can't see the player class, so this is pseudo code)

```
function change_dir(d) {
    this.d += d;
}
```

Invoke the function in `keyReleased` and `keyPressed` when <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> is pressed respectively released:

```js
function keyReleased() {

    if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
        players.change_dir(-2)
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        players.change_dir(2)
    }
}

function keyPressed() {

    if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
        players.change_dir(2)
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        players.change_dir(-2)
    }
}
```